# Spring REST 405

Tags: java, spring, rest

I made this rest, for first look all must to work properly, but I catch 405.

> HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported

Application Context

```
@Bean
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager){
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);

        List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();
        resolvers.add(getViewResolver());
        resolvers.add(jsonViewResolver());

        resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
        return resolver;
    }   

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver jsonViewResolver(){
        return new JsonViewResolver();
    }
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/create/{login}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public @ResponseBody User updateUser(@RequestBody User user, @PathVariable String login){
        dao.saveUser(user);
        return user;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `method = RequestMethod.PUT` to `method = RequestMethod.GET`, or use PUT request on existing mapping.

If you don't want to use plugins, you can create PUT request using jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: someUrl,
    data: someData, 
    type: 'PUT',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

Comment: Then use PUT as method. How are you making requests? If from browser, use some plugin like Postman for Chrome, or Poster for Firefox.

Comment: i want to make from browser, without any plugins to start

Comment: Ok, try one of those plugins, with them you can customize your requests as you want.

Comment: Well, if you just write the url in browser and hit enter, it's going to be a GET request.

Comment: Then i must to use only through plugin?

Comment: Or from code, javascript, you can use jQuery to make a PUT request.

Comment: Yes, you only have to make a proper request to match it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `RequestMethod.PUT` to `RequestMethod.GET`

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/rest/create/{login}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

If you want to use put method then modify your HTML form tag and controller accordingly

Example **HTML Form**

```
 <form:form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" method="PUT" action="Temp.htm" enctype="multipart/form-data" commandName="tempBean">
```

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/create/{login}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
```